# update-manager doesn't show after upgrading from 16.04

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, update-manager

I just upgraded my Lubuntu 16.04 to 17.04. But after the upgrade, update-manager doesn't show any more.

I've tried `update-manager`, `update-manager -v`, and `update-manager --help` from the command line. But the commands just return immediately without showing the GUI or giving any output.

Has anyone had similar experience or know of a solution?

--Update --

It seems that the problem is more than update-manager. When I launch `Startup Disk Creator`, `Synaptic Package Manager` from `System Tools`, the same thing happens. The mouse cursor turns into a wait/busy cursor for some seconds, and then silence. But `Task Manager` works as usual.

As suggested by the comments, the output of `dpkg -l` and `ls -l` are below:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep update-manager
ii  python3-update-manager                 1:17.04.8                                       all          python 3.x module for update-manager
ii  update-manager                         1:17.04.8                                       all          GNOME application that manages apt updates
ii  update-manager-core                    1:17.04.8                                       all          manage release upgrades

$ ls -l /usr/bin/update-manager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4793 Sep 20 16:36 /usr/bin/update-manager
```

Comment: I'd check if it's installed with `dpkg -l | grep update-manager`, and if not, install it, and if yes, check permissions with `ls -l /usr/bin/update-manager`. Sorry if it's too obvious.

Comment: How did you upgrade ? Did you skip 16.10 ? Considering you are having multiple problems, probably best to back up your data and do a fresh install as debugging your current system, and then all the changes to 17.10 is going to take longer and be less reliable.

Comment: @Panther I used update-manager GUI to upgrade to 17.04 directly. Many GUI's stopped working after that, including update-manager, emacs etc..

Comment: You can not skip releases when upgrading. https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading , Again I advise you fresh install.

Comment: @Panther update-manager didn't give me 16.10 as an option to upgrade to, if I recall.

Comment: Because 6.10 is beyond end of life https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Skipping releases is possible...if you have the skills...but is it *unsupported* beasue it sometimes causes precisely the problems you are having - random breakage. You are asking for support after doing an unsupported action. Most of the advice you get will be variations on the excellent @Panther said first.

Comment: Just to be fair, I'm upgrading from the *current* LTS to the *current* non-LTS version. Why isn't this supported or require skills in the first place? @user535733  Sure, everyone knows to start from scratch. But that's exactly what I wanted to avoid, i.e. to resintall/configure all the packages on the current machine.

Comment: It's not supported simply because it introduces another path that needs to be re-tested and debugged every six months. If more volunteers wanted to spend their evenings testing and troubleshooting that particular path, then it would be supported.